# Drop-down links to show pages from index view Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, url-routing

I'm building a Rails app and want the links to the Show pages of each instance of my Class to appear in a drop-down on the Index page. I'm currently using a select_tag with options_from_collection_for_select but it doesn't seem to register the relevant :id to navigate to the Show page.

Is there a way of achieving this without using Javascript? Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to submit form on `selected`, you have to use `javascript` else below code you can use

```
<% form_tag :url => { :controller => "my_controller", :action => "show", :id => id }, :method => :get do %>
   <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(@myObjects, :id, :name) %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Show' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: here's my code:                                                                                           <%= form_tag "/constituencies/show", :method => :get do %>
    <%= select_tag :id, options_from_collection_for_select(Constituency.all, "id", "name"), {prompt: 'Select Constituency'} %>
    <%= submit_tag  %>
    <% end %>

Comment: when i submit i get this url "/constituencies/show?utf8=✓&id=6&commit=Save+changes" - how do i get it just to add the #id to the url without the utf8 etc (in this case '/6'? any help much appreciated!!

Comment: Try `<% form_tag constituency_path, :method => :get do %>`

Comment: Or Try this `<form action="<%= constituency_path %>" method="get" >`

Comment: I get this error when trying this... No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"constituencies"} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Do you have `@constituency` object here

Comment: I do in the show method within the controller - not within Index though - should I? Am I not passing it the :id within the options_from_collection_for_select tag??